# How to calculate the time that has passed since a file was created

Tags: c#, file, date, time

I want to calculate the time since the file was created, for example if the file was created 12 months ago I want to delete it.
I have this right now:

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(path);
```

Thank you!

Comment: just get the current DateTime and compare them!

Comment: Have a look at [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan(v=vs.80).aspx) and [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(path);
TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileCreatedDate);
if(difference.TotalDays > 365)
{

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Substract fileCreatedDate from DateTime.Now - that should work:

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(path);

var timespan = DateTime.Now - fileCreatedDate;
if(timespan.Days > 365)
{
   File.Delete(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
  DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(path);

  if((DateTime.Now - fileCreatedDate ).Days > 365)
  {
        File.Delete(path);
  }
```